# Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType is not supported

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, schema

I try to create empty df with schema:

```
  val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName("app")
    .setMaster("local")

  val sparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate()

  val sparkContext = sparkSession.sparkContext

  var tmpScheme = StructType(
    StructField("source_id", StringType, true) :: Nil)

var df = conf.SparkConf.sparkSession.createDataFrame(tmpScheme)
```

and got `Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType is not supported ...`

I don't understand why - there is no `.DataType` even in Imports:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{BooleanType, IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}
```

What can be the problem here?

PS: spark version

```
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.2.2", // spark
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.2.2", // spark
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you check the documentation, you can see that the argument `fields` of `StructType` is of type `Array[StructField]` and you are passing `StructField`.

This means that you should wrap your `StructField` with `Array`, for example:

```
val simpleSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("source_id", StringType, true))
)
```

Good luck!

**EDIT**

The case with one parameter in `createDataframe`:

```
val data = Seq(
  Data(1, "test"),
  Data(2, "test2")
)
val dataDf = spark.createDataFrame(data)
dataDf.show(10, false)
```

The case with two parameterse in `createDataframe`:

```
val someSchema = List(
  StructField("number", IntegerType, true),
  StructField("word", StringType, true)
)
val someData = Seq(Row(1, "test"), Row(2, "test2"))
val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)
```

The output for both cases is the same:

```
+------+-----+
|number|word |
+------+-----+
|1     |test |
|2     |test2|
+------+-----+
```

In your case, the schema is trying to be inferred from attributes of the class (`StructType`) and is trying to be populated with `StructField: source_id`. `StructType` extends `DataType` and that is where your error comes from (Spark can not resolve the type)

Comment: The point is that I am passing `StructField("source_id", StringType, true) :: Nil` 
which is a `List[org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField]` and not just `StructField`

but nevertheless even with evident Array(...) I get same error

Comment: Oh I get your point, my bad. `createDataframe` with one argument, is a sequence of data to be populated, not a schema. You can use `createDataframe` with one argument through a case class, but if you want to use both `schema` and `data`, you can use `createDataset(data, schema)` because in your case, Spark is trying to create a dataframe with data of type `StructType`